# Find the additive and multiplicative inverse of $-36$

Tags: arithmetic

Find the additive and multiplicative inverse of $-36$.

I don't remember how to do these problems. If you can help that would be great. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  To be an inverse, you apply the operation to that and your number and need to get the identity.  What is the additive identity?  What can you add to $-36$ to get that?  Same for multiplication.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. My brain is on math overload. Been working on it all day.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=additive+inverse The Wikipedia article is a good start

Comment: thanks! :) additive inverse makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

For additive inverse you want a number $x$ such that $-36+x=0$ For multiplicative inverse you want a number $y$ such thast $-36*y=1$(For example in this one the multiplicative inverse for $2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ since $\frac{1}{2}*2=1=2*\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: :) thanks! I am starting to remember how to do them.